# Kafka with Docker Swarm - How to execute Kafka commands

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, dockerfile, docker-swarm, docker-machine

I am new to Kafka and I am a little confused.

So far I have created two docker machines, a manager and a worker with these commands:

```
docker-machine create manager
docker-machine create worker1
```

I have add these two nodes inside a docker swarm.

```
docker@manager:~$ docker node ls                                                                                                                                                                             
ID                            HOSTNAME            STATUS              AVAILABILITY        MANAGER STATUS      ENGINE VERSION
6bmovp3hr0j2w5irmexvvjgzq *   manager             Ready               Active              Leader              19.03.5
mtgbd9bg8d6q0lk9ycw10bxos     worker1             Ready               Active                                  19.03.5
```

I want to create a kafka cluster inside docker swarm. My `docker-compose.yml` looks like this

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:latest
    ports:
      - target: 9094
        published: 9094
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    environment:
      HOSTNAME_COMMAND: "hostname | awk -F'-' '{print $$2}'"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://_{HOSTNAME_COMMAND}:9094
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://:9094
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

where `hostname | awk -F'-' '{print $$2}'` command returns `manager` of `worker`.

Then I deploy with the command `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml kafka` which returns

```
Creating network kafka_default
Creating service kafka_zookeeper
Creating service kafka_kafka
```

I checked that th service is running with `docker service ls`

```
ID                  NAME                MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                           PORTS
ttprq3ak98om        kafka_kafka         replicated          0/1                 wurstmeister/kafka:latest       
vxdhkaonrbpe        kafka_zookeeper     replicated          0/1                 wurstmeister/zookeeper:latest   *:2181->2181/tcp
```

and then I scale the service with `docker service scale kafka_kafka=2`. When I execute `docker service ps kafka_kafka` I get

```
ID                  NAME                IMAGE                       NODE                DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE            ERROR               PORTS
ydn64mwvlasr        kafka_kafka.1       wurstmeister/kafka:latest   worker1             Running             Running 27 minutes ago                       *:9094->9094/tcp
shkpd2jv6s29        kafka_kafka.2       wurstmeister/kafka:latest   manager             Running             Running 27 minutes ago                       *:9094->9094/tcp
```

So far I have one ZooKeeper and two Kafka brokers. One broker on manager and one on worker. This means that the broker on worker replicates the broker on manager?

Also I wonder how to run Kafka commands in this step. Suppose that I want to create a topic. How can I achieve this? I have to download Kafka binary from here: https://kafka.apache.org/downloads? And if the answer is yes, I have to strat the zookeeper server? Is it not running already?

Comment: Docker Machine is basically deprecated, AFAIK, why use it? Also, you don't need to mount the `docker.sock` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to run kafka commands inside the container you need to first get the kafka container id

```
$ docker ps -a  
  CONTAINER ID                 IMAGE  
   1239075412         wurstmeister/kafka:latest
```

now take this container id(will be different in your case) of kafka

```
$ docker exec -it 1239075412 sh
```

logs are present in the following folder

```
# cd kafka/kafka-logs-1239075412
```

kafka commands will be present in this container type kafka- and then hit tab twice
you will get all the kafka commands to create **topics** etc..

Answer (score 1):

> This means that the broker on worker replicates the broker on manager?

For purposes of your question, Kafka can be described as master-less. All broker function equally and their processes only communicate to one another for replication.

(If you want to get into internals, you can study about the Controller process, which runs on one of the brokers)

> I have to strat the zookeeper server? Is it not running already?

Yes, it is. Ref - `kafka_zookeeper` image.

> Suppose that I want to create a topic. How can I achieve this?

Well, you could skip using CLI commands at all and use another container such as the [Kafka topic manager](https://github.com/yahoo/CMAK)

> I have to download Kafka binary from here

Otherwise, yes / no. If you want to create topics **from your host**, then yeah. **Inside a container** works as well (hint: learn `docker-compose exec`)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So zookeeper is running as well as Kafka. How can I create topics? I don't understand clear this part "...Well, you could skip using CLI commands at all..". If I don't want to skip CLI commands what to do? Sorry, I am new to docker and kafka.

Comment: You run the service I linked to. As a Docker container, or not. If you're new to both technologies, then don't use both. Just install Kafka and Zookeeper alone based on the official kafka website. I would strongly suggest not starting learning Docker through Kafka or Zookeeper